# Access denied when registering a custom timer job

Tags: timer-jobs

I am getting a SecurityException while trying to activate a feature with a custom timer job. The error is raised from the job.Update() method call. I am running the code with Farm Admin account.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: To confirm, you are registering the job as part of a feature receiver and activating the feature through CA logged in as the Farm Admin, correct?

Answer (score 4):

Try to override the [SPPersistedObject.HasAdditionalUpdateAccess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppersistedobject.hasadditionalupdateaccess.aspx) method and return *true*.

```
protected override bool HasAdditionalUpdateAccess()
{
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22757/configure-sharepoint-user-for-timer-job) for you. Your application pool identity will not have the appropriate rights. This thread contains full information how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think the thread doesn't apply to my problem. Because I am trying to install the timer job with the Farm Administrator account which already has full access to both Content DB and SharePoint API.

Comment: But you try to execute your code from frontend role. In this case your permissions are reduced by security reasons.