# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when Updating a Timer JOB?

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

This is really weird.

The exception is thrown in the FeatureActivated event exactly in the line `job.Update()`. There is no way to debug any further because that method is from the framework.  Maybe I am missing to set more properties in the instantiation of the object??

```
 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
            {

                // Get an instance of the SharePoint farm.
                SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;

                // Get an instance of the service.
                var results = from s in farm.Services
                              where s.Name == "SynchronizationUserAccessListJob"
                              select s;

                SPService service = results.FirstOrDefault();

                // Remove job if it exists.
                if (service != null)
                {
                    DeleteJob(service);
                }

                // Create the job.
                SynchronizationUserAccessListJob job = new SynchronizationUserAccessListJob();


                // Create the schedule so that the job runs hourly, sometime 
                // during the first quarter of the hour.
                SPHourlySchedule schedule = new SPHourlySchedule();
                schedule.BeginMinute = 0;
                schedule.EndMinute = 5;
                job.Schedule = schedule;
                job.Update();            
            }




 public SynchronizationUserAccessListJob() : base() 
        {
            this.Title = "SynchronizationUserAccessListJob";
        }

        public SynchronizationUserAccessListJob(string jobname, SPService service)
            : base(jobname, service, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
        {
            this.Title = jobname;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// The timer job actually executes this method depending on its configuration, It will be done, every day.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetInstanceId"></param>
        public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
        {
```

Comment: What scope of feature do you use?

Comment: farm scope!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SPWeb or SPSite feature scope you can have a problem with security. Read [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22710/web-scoped-timer-job) or [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22757/configure-sharepoint-user-for-timer-job) for more details.

I suggest you to use the SPFarm or SPWebApplication scoped feature. There is no problem with security.

Comment: its farm scoped.

Comment: but then, whats the problem with my code? I wonder if the problem is with the object SPService.